# Настройка пагинации для класса Listview

Tags: python, django

Есть два класса для вывода товаров на страницу и две модели Category и Product:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название категории')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                        related_name='children', verbose_name='Родительская категория',
                               help_text='В какую категорию входит')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('products-by-category', args=[int(self.pk)])

    

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Наименование')
    producer = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Производитель')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category', max_length=255, verbose_name='Категория')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание', blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Единицы измерения', blank=True, null=True, default='шт')
    vendor_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Артикул', blank=True, help_text='Напишите свой или система создаст его автоматчиески')
    for_car = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Подходит для', blank=True)
    price_purch = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Цена закупки', max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    price_sell = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Цена продажи', max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    price_revision = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Цена с переоценкой', max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    sold = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Продано', default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    balance = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Остаток', default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Видимость')
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img-products/%Y/', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name', 'category')
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товары'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class Home(ListView):
model = Product
template_name = 'landing/products.html'
context_object_name = 'products'
paginate_by = 12

def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = 'Товары'
    products = Product.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context['categories'] = categories
    return context


class ProductsByCategoryView(ListView):
model = Product
context_object_name = 'products'
template_name = 'landing/products.html'
paginate_by = 2

def get_queryset(self):
    self.category = Category.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(category=self.category)
    return queryset

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['title'] = 'Товары'
    products = Product.objects.filter(availability=True).order_by('name')
    if self.category:
        sub_categories = self.category.get_descendants(include_self=True)
        products = products.filter(category__in=sub_categories)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context['categories'] = categories
    context['products'] = products
    return context
```

Есть два класса ListView и они выводят товары в шаблон (не понял как сделать вывод товаров по категориям через один класс, но получилось через два. Если есть мысль как превратить это в один аккуратный класс, то рад был бы услышать об этом).

Вопрос в следующем:

1)Через класс Home выводится весь список товаров, добавил в шаблон пагинацию и всё работает.
Через класс ProductsByCategoryView выводятся товары в зависимости от того какую категорию выбирают в списке и при этом учитывается вложенность категорий. Добавил пагинацию и она работает только для конечных потомков в категориях, а вложенность, если выбрать коренную категорию не учитывается и там нет пагинации.

2)Пробовал сделать по примеру класса Home, то на пагинация считает каждый товар отдельной страницей, и переходе на страницу присутствуют все товары. Как адекватно настроить пагинацию для вывода по категориям?